# Play framework CompilationException

Tags: java, exception, playframework, compiler-errors

I am trying to precompile a play 1.2.5 project when I have this error:

```
Compilation error (In /app/controllers/api/Drivers.java around line 168)
The file /app/controllers/api/Drivers.java could not be compiled. 
Error raised is : driverResume cannot be resolved or is not a field

play.exceptions.CompilationException: driverResume cannot be resolved or is not a field
at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler$2.acceptResult(ApplicationCompiler.java:246)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.handleInternalException(Compiler.java:676)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:520)
at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler.compile(ApplicationCompiler.java:282)
at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:426)
at play.Play.preCompile(Play.java:593)
at play.Play.init(Play.java:299)
at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:159)
```

The driverResume field is public and visible in the Driver class.

I tried on different computers with jdk 1.6.0 and I always get the same exception.

Does anyone know how to have more information about the precompile process, compiler logic, or has already run into this kind of issue?

Comment: Can you post some parts of `Drivers.java`? Namely, where you define `driverResume`, the class declaration, and the lines around 168 where the error is happening (ideally, that whole controller method).

Comment: What is the type of driverResume? Are there any compiler errors with that type?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be an issue where you are mis-reading the compile error. The compiler is complaining about the Drivers class, and you say that the field is public in the Driver (not Drivers) class.

Could this be the problem?